# how to parse &nbsp; in iphone xml?

Tags: iphone

```
50%&nbsp;(103 votes)
```

The above tag is one of the tags from my XML, now I'm getting the following error at the time of parsing:-

error parsing XML: Unable to download story feed from the website (Error code 26 )

please help me out of this problem...

Comment: Could you show the fragment above with some more context?

Comment: <game_view>

  <date>2011-04-15</date>

  <time>19:00:00</time>

  <datetime>2011-04-15 19:00:00</datetime>

  <roadteam>Tampa Bay</roadteam>

  <roadteamshow>50%&nbsp;(103 votes)</roadteamshow>

  <hometeam>*Pittsburgh</hometeam>

  <hometeamshow>50%&nbsp;(99 votes)</hometeamshow>

  </game_view>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when you have mismatches in xml tags. Check the tags in xml with your rss feed page source xml tags.

Comment: i have checked the tags in xml and rss feed page source xml tags,there are no mismatches of xml tags.According to me i m getting error bcos &nbsp; is a special character so for this i wrote the following coding before parsing :-NSString *dataString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
NSData *data = [dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

Comment: Use the following code project for a good rss reader.Also you can download the source code from this link: http://gigaom.com/apple/tutorial-build-a-simple-rss-reader-for-iphone/

Comment: <game_view>

  <date>2011-04-15</date>

  <time>19:00:00</time>

  <datetime>2011-04-15 19:00:00</datetime>

  <roadteam>Tampa Bay</roadteam>

  <roadteamshow>50%&nbsp;(103 votes)</roadteamshow>

  <hometeam>*Pittsburgh</hometeam>

  <hometeamshow>50%&nbsp;(99 votes)</hometeamshow>

  </game_view>